# How to distinguish "are" and "aren't" in American accent?

Tags: pronunciation

The question have confused me for a long time. How to distinguish "are" and "aren't" in American accent? Usually, the pronunciations are:

1. *are* is pronounced as /ə/ or /ɑ:r/
2. *aren't* is pronounced as /'ɑːrənt/

According to my hearing, many Americans would omit the final /t/ in *aren't*, making it /'ɑːrən/, which is very close to the pronunciation of *are(/ɑ:r/)*. In fact, I almost cannot find any difference.You can hear this sentence [here](http://chirb.it/9dAmt1). It says: *These aren't the only governors touting comebacks.* But for me, the *aren't* in the sentence is more like an *are*, isn't it? Can anyone tell me how to distinguish the two words? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, it's *comeback* in your clip. I'm not sure but it's possible that your clip was cut off before the /s/ sound.

Comment: There are several cues I use to distinguish are and aren't. First, aren't usually got more stressed than are. Second, even though you can't hear the /t/ sound, it's likely that you can hear the /n/ sound after /r/. Third, the "pitch contour" (the rising and falling of the intonation native speakers use) of are and aren't are usually different. Finally, and this might be the hardest one for non-native speakers to observe, is the quality of the "stop" of /t/ sound. Almost always, you could hear some quality of choppiness of this /t/ sound. Afaict, all cues are in your clip. [fixed misspellings]

Comment: Context helps a lot. If you're still not sure, you can always ask, "Did you say _are_, or _are not_?"

Comment: Also: the negative will never be unstressed, while the positive may be; and even if the /rnt/ is greatly reduced, the vowel will usually be nasalized.

Comment: Native speakers do what J.R. said regularly, by the way.

Comment: Hmm... I'm a native speaker, but the clip sounded like "aren't" to me, not "are." I could hear both the 'n' and the 't' sound, though the audio quality made it more faint than it probably was in person. While some - particularly those with a thick Southern accent - do leave off the 't' sound, it seems to me that most Americans (including even most in the Southeast) do pronounce it. Maybe if we're talking quickly someone who isn't used to it just can't hear it well?

Comment: Also, in recordings, the low pitch of the 't' sound can cause it to not be detected well by low-quality microphones or played well by low-quality speakers. Small speakers (and microphones,) in particular, have trouble picking up the bass range where that sound mostly resides. I remember looking a data sheet for a 2" speaker we were using once and it had a 50 dB drop from 500 Hz to 50 Hz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm from the Southeastern US.  That omitting the final "t" sound is in a good many words.  But when we do it, we usually pronounce the last sound a little differently than usual.  I mean, it's basically the same sound, but we time it differently and such.

For example, even though we don't pronounce the "t" in "aren't", we still say "aren't" differently than we would "aren'".  Same thing between "different" and "differen", or "mitigate" and "mitigae".

It's real difficult to describe the difference on paper.  It's kind of like we don't say the last sound quite as long, or that we stop making the last sound very suddenly.  Except that might not be 100% true, and we really slightly alter the sound into something more like a gutteral whisper, and we use something like a different, harsher tone.  In this way, relatively soft sounds like "ay" and "n" are kind of hardened and are made to sound more like "ayt" or "nt".  We fake the "t" sound essentially.  Again it's something really hard to describe, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I'm from the Midwest US. When pronouncing *aren't* in a sentence, I replace the [t] with a glottal stop [ʔ]. So in a sentence starting *Those are the only...* I pronounce *are the* as [arðə]. While in *Those aren't the only...*, I say [arʔðə], also with a bit of nasalization before the glottal stop (not sure how to write this). Listening to your recording, this is exactly what that speaker did -- there's a noticeable gap between *aren't* and *the*.

Answer (score 3):

*Are* in everyday speech will often (almost always?) be part of a contraction with the pronoun *they*, i.e. "they're", whereas *aren't* (are not) won't be contracted with the pronoun, and it will receive some emphasis.  So, frequently the parsing rhythm combined with the difference in vowel sounds (they're, they aren't) will be the best clue.

They're háppy to do it.

They áren't happy to do it.

But how to distinguish "they are" from "they aren't"?  Native speakers will say "are" quickly and with hardly any emphasis whatsoever, whereas "aren't" will be given much greater emphasis.

They are háppy to do it.

They áren't happy to do it.

The speaking in that recording is on the rapid end of the spectrum. But if you listen, the word *aren't* in  "these aren't" receives considerably greater emphasis than 'these'...  *These áren't*.

Comment: +1. When I want to emphasize "are" in a sentence, I feel like I ought to put an exaggerated amount of emphasis on it, lengthening the word. Probably because otherwise, it'd sound too close to aren't?